# Error al insertar registros en SQL Server (BULK INSERT)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema al insertar los registros de una tabla con el comando BULK INSERT.

**BULK**
    **Insert** producto
    **from** 'C:\csv\productos.csv'
    **with** (firstrow = 2, fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')

Este es el error que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información de la tabla en el archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Información de los campos de la tabla:

[image]

Comment: Tengo duda por que la última Columna la del error los datos inician con comillas pero al final ya no se les pones?

Comment: ¿No deberían ir la segunda y tercera columna entre comillas al ser cadenas de texto?

Answer (score 1):

Verifica el archivo de la data, aparenta haber un caracter desconocido.

Te recomiendo que abras el archivo con notepad++, activandole show all characters. Asi puedes ver si hay algún caracter dando problemas

Otra cosa,

si el ID se genera automatico, no deberias tenerlo en la data de entrada